# How can I reference a DOM element in a function that makes an action call?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a functional component that I would like to use an onClick in to dispatch an action for a simple like button. I the onClick function to take in the store properties of the DOM element it refers to in order to update the store slice it is designed to affect.

I've tried to pass in the data as props, to no avail. I've also tried using a react Ref, but this seems to be reserved for class components

**The component that handles the click**

The likes and content are passed down from the Redux store via props from a parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../scss/styles.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {onNewLike} from './../actions';

function Post(props){


  function doALike() {
    const { dispatch } = props
    dispatch(onNewLike())
  }

    return(
      <div className="post">
        <h1>{props.content}</h1>
        <div className="post-statistics">
          <p onClick={doALike}>LIKE</p>
          <p>likes: {props.likes}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

Post.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.string,
  likes: PropTypes.number,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
}


export default connect()(Post)
```

**The Reducer I am trying to pass the post to, so that I can update each unique post's likes (haven't written the logic for handling a like yet - just want to make sure I'm getting each post's likes**

```
import { initialState } from '../constants/initialState';
import c from './../constants';

export function likeReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type){
  case c.NEW_LIKE:
    console.log(action.id)
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

**The component that allows users to generate a new post, and passes 'likes' set to '0' to the redux store**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../scss/styles.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {onNewPost} from './../actions';


function NewPost({dispatch}){


    let _content = null;

    function handleNewPost(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let post = {content: _content.value, likes: 69, id: v4()}
      dispatch(onNewPost(post))
    }

  return(
    <div className='newPost'>
      <h1>Create a Post</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleNewPost}>
        <input type='text'
          id='content'
          className='newPostInput'
          placeholder='Whats on your mind?'
          ref={(input) => {_content = input;}}/>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in what you need to the `doALike` function and then call it in the click handler as an anonymous function like below.

```
function Post(props){
    function doALike(whateverProps) {
        dispatch(onNewLike())
      }

        return(
          <div className="post">
            <h1>{props.content}</h1>
            <div className="post-statistics">
              <p onClick={() => {doALike(props)}}>LIKE</p>
              <p>likes: {props.likes}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: I am trying this, but anything inside doALike still comes back undefined. Can you elaborate a bit? Thanks @James Morrison

Comment: @JackCollins how/where are you rending your Post component?